# Python not Cooperating

Tags: python, r

I am creating a joint project using both Python and R in Visual Studio. I imported Tkinter from Python to create the interface and using R via rpy2 for analyzing data. I am stuck with this error code:

```
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\15309\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\Lib\io.py", line 54, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'open_code' from 'io' (unknown location)
```

I am using Python 3.7 in Visual Studio and rpy2 is imported from Anaconda's Python 3.7. My instructor and I have not been able to figure out how to fix it. What do we need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your filename is io.py
Change its name to something else.

Comment: From what I understand, io.py is the default interface for files and streams for all Python versions 3 and higher. I don't understand how to fix the error because it is the default interface that everything should be going through already.